# Thymeleaf pass object to javascript and access it properties: undefined

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I have spent many hours researching this and applied all the solutions but can't get my code to work. I have a select which holds an object as value (cannot change due to data binding) onchange, it calls a js function which accesses the id property of object held by value attribute but returns undefined. Is there a way to access this. I have tried JSON.parse and JSON.stringify and a combination of the 2 on the object without success.

here is my select:

```
<select th:field="*{category}" class="custom-select" id="category" style="padding: 0px" onchange="getInstitutions()">
       <option value="a" selected>select one..</i></option>
       <option th:each="category : ${categories}"
                    th:value="${category}"
                    th:text="${category.name}"
                    th:data="${category.id}"
                    selected></option>
</select>
```

Here is my JS function:

```
function getInstitutions() {
    var cat = $("#category").val();
    //cat=JSON.stringify(cat);
    var catId=cat.id;
    alert(catId); // undefined
    // use id to query db using ajax...
}
```

Comment: can you show `$("#category").val()` this value

Comment: You dont have a chance to evaluate and obtain the id field of the object dynamically in your JS function once the template is rendered. You can do two things. 1) You can assign your `object.id` value to your option value by `th.value="${category.id}"` and then obtain and use it in your JS. 2) You can use a custom attribute of option like you did it in your `th:data="${category.id}"` and get it in your JS

Comment: Thanks @prasanth and Ahmet. I have used ${category.id} then i bind the data later in the controller save method